# pandas dataframe list col, do a str.split('\.[a-zA-Z]', 1).str[0].str.strip() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: pandas

```
data = {
             'IDs':  ['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5','G6'],
            'hostname': [[ 'Gp.xyz.com', 'Gp.wxyz.com'],['GSS'],['CS.xyz.com', 'CS_B.wxyz.com'],['GS191'], ['C_P.g.com'][10.10.1.10]]
       } 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
    Out[107]: 
  IDs                     hostname
0  G1    [Gp.xyz.com, Gp.wxyz.com]
1  G2                        [GSS]
2  G3  [CS.xyz.com, CS_B.wxyz.com]
3  G4                      [GS191]
4  G5                  [C_P.g.com]
5  g6                 [10.10.1.10]

df['hostname'].apply(lambda el: [ x.str.split('\.[a-zA-Z]', 1).str[0].str.strip() for x in el])
```

I tried the following for column with single element it worked. but the above was giving me an error,

```
line 1, in <listcomp>
    df['hostname'].apply(lambda el: [ x.str.split('\.[a-zA-Z]', 1).str[0].str.strip() for x in el])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

expected output should be in the following format,

```
data1 = {
         'IDs':  ['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5'],
        'hostname': [[ 'Gp', 'Gp'],['GSS'],['CS', 'CS_B'],['GS191'], ['C_P']]
   } 

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df1
  Out[108]: 
  IDs    hostname
0  G1    [Gp, Gp]
1  G2       [GSS]
2  G3  [CS, CS_B]
3  G4     [GS191]
4  G5       [C_P]
5  G6 [10.10.1.10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do `explode` first then `split`

```
s=df.explode('hostname')
s['hostname']=s.hostname.str.split('\.[a-zA-Z]', 1).str[0]
s.groupby(level=0).agg({'IDs':'first','hostname':list})
  IDs    hostname
0  G1    [Gp, Gp]
1  G2       [GSS]
2  G3  [CS, CS_B]
3  G4     [GS191]
4  G5       [C_P]
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: I got some reduced rows when i tried in my actual dataframe

Comment: @vinsentparamananthamv check the update `s.groupby(level=0).agg({'IDs':'first','hostname':list})
`, the reason you have reduced row , is Ids is not unique , which contain duplicate

Answer (score 0):

For your error, since you use `apply`, each `x` is a python string, e.g `'Gp.xyz.com'`. So it does not have `.str` access. You can just do `x.split('.')`, but I doubt you can use regex split there. A fix would be

```
df['hostname'].apply(lambda el: [x.split('.')[0] for x in el])
```

Another modification to Ben's solution is to use `extract`, saving some `.str` access:

```
s=df.explode('hostname')
s['hostname']=s.hostname.str.extract('^([^\.]*)')
s.groupby('IDs').agg(list)
```

Output:

```
    hostname
IDs     
G1  [Gp, Gp]
G2  [GSS]
G3  [CS, CS_B]
G4  [GS191]
G5  [C_P]
```

Comment: On Ben's answer I am getting a reduced count of my dataframe.. Let me try x.split('.')

Comment: .apply(lambda el: [ x.split('\.[a-zA-Z]')[0] for x in el]) , AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham just use `'.'` as mentioned in the answer. See updates.

Comment: Sorry I have IPs also in the hostname like 10.101.10.1, thats the reason I am using only alphabets..

Comment: df['hostname'].apply(lambda el: [x.split('.')[0]  for x in el]) my ip is truncated to 5          [10]

Comment: Use ` '^((\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?[^\.]*)'` in the second solution.

Comment: df['hostname'].apply(lambda el: [x.split('^((\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?[^\.]*)') for x in el])  i, tried this but no actions, it the same text again.